# Java: Adding/Subtracting Math.ulp() vs. Math.nextAfter()

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm trying to understand floating point operations in Java in more detail. If I read the documentation correctly, the following holds for any given double x:

```
x - Math.ulp(x) == Math.nextAfter(x, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
x + Math.ulp(x) == Math.nextAfter(x, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

Question: Is this always the case or are there some exceptional cases in which results will differ?

Comment: Looking at what happens at integer powers of two, such as 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0 etc. should give you important insight into floating point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 1;
    System.out.println(x - Math.ulp(x) == Math.nextAfter(x, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    System.out.println(x + Math.ulp(x) == Math.nextAfter(x, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
false
true
```

The difference between consecutive doubles changes at each normal integer power of two, including 1.0. One of the tests must fail, because it assumes constant difference. [Math.ulp(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-) is defined to return "the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude" so the subtract proposition is false when the distance is different.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate cases I'd think to check are 0, +infinity and -infinity and NaN:

```
static void check(double x) {
  double a, b;
  System.out.printf(
      "%9s %9s %23s %5s%n",
      x, a = x - Math.ulp(x), b = Math.nextAfter(x, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY), a == b);
  System.out.printf(
      "%9s %9s %23s %5s%n",
      x, a = x + Math.ulp(x), b = Math.nextAfter(x, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY), a == b);
  System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  check(0);
  check(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
  check(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
  check(Double.NaN);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PvtomN)

Output:

```
      0.0 -4.9E-324               -4.9E-324  true
      0.0  4.9E-324                4.9E-324  true

 Infinity       NaN  1.7976931348623157E308 false
 Infinity  Infinity                Infinity  true

-Infinity -Infinity               -Infinity  true
-Infinity       NaN -1.7976931348623157E308 false

      NaN       NaN                     NaN false
      NaN       NaN                     NaN false
```

That the expressions aren't equal in the `NaN` case isn't surprising (by the definition of NaN); but these expressions also aren't true for +infinity and -infinity (see the last column).

This answer is not intended to provide an exhaustive list of problematic values, but rather to show that some problematic values do exist.

Comment: That you can't "increment" +Infinity makes sense.It should work for "normal" numbers though.

Comment: @assylias yep, but OP asks "are there some exceptional cases in which results will differ?"

Comment: Given that the accepted answer shows it doesn't work for any power of two (in particular for 1.0), I think this is ... somewhat misleading.

Comment: @MartinBonner why is it misleading? It's clear it didn't work in these cases. OP asks if there are some, this demonstrates there are.

Comment: It's misleading because they OP might think those are the only ones (and they can easily avoid NAN and infinities).  I suspect most people ignore those cases; 1.0 is a bit harder to ignore.